# How to add ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG MAXIMUS XI FORMULA w_in and w_out sensors in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, asus

I've installed the *lm-sensors* package and ran the command sensors-detect, however it does not seem to get any of the w_in or w_out sensors from the asus motherboard.

Here is the output of *sudo sensors-detect*

```
sudo sensors-detect
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# Board: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG MAXIMUS XI FORMULA
# Kernel: 6.5.0-15-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9900K CPU @ 3.60GHz (6/158/12)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): 
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               Yes
Found `Nuvoton NCT6798D Super IO Sensors'                   Success!
    (address 0x290, driver `nct6775')
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): 
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (yes/NO): yes
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.4: Cannon Lake-H (PCH)

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at efa0 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
Client found at address 0x18
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for `Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP400'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments AMC6821'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95233'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95234'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95235'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95245'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM64'...                No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1047'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1402'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1403'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1404'...                               No
Probing for `ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `IDT TSE2004'...                                No
Probing for `IDT TS3001'...                                 No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9808'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS02C'...                              No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS04'...                               No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Probing for `Giantec GT30TS00'...                           No
Client found at address 0x19
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for `Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP400'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments AMC6821'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95231'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95241'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95245'...             No
Probing for `ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `IDT TSE2004'...                                No
Probing for `IDT TS3001'...                                 No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9808'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS02C'...                              No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS04'...                               No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Probing for `Giantec GT30TS00'...                           No
Client found at address 0x1a
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for `Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP400'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments AMC6821'...                  No
Probing for `ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `IDT TSE2004'...                                No
Probing for `IDT TS3001'...                                 No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9808'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS02C'...                              No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS04'...                               No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Probing for `Giantec GT30TS00'...                           No
Client found at address 0x1b
Probing for `ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `IDT TSE2004'...                                No
Probing for `IDT TS3001'...                                 No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9808'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS02C'...                              No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS04'...                               No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Probing for `Giantec GT30TS00'...                           No
Client found at address 0x50
Handled by driver `ee1004' (already loaded), chip type `ee1004'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)
Client found at address 0x51
Handled by driver `ee1004' (already loaded), chip type `ee1004'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)
Client found at address 0x52
Handled by driver `ee1004' (already loaded), chip type `ee1004'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)
Client found at address 0x53
Handled by driver `ee1004' (already loaded), chip type `ee1004'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)
Client found at address 0x77
Probing for `Asus Mozart-2'...                              No

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at 1:00.0 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 5 at 1:00.0 (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 6 at 1:00.0 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 7 at 1:00.0 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 8 at 1:00.0 (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Driver `nct6775':
  * ISA bus, address 0x290
    Chip `Nuvoton NCT6798D Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
nct6775
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

*Output of cat /etc/modules*

```
cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.


# Generated by sensors-detect on Wed Jan 31 19:26:55 2024
# Chip drivers
coretemp
nct6775
```

Output of *sensors*

```
sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +41.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +40.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +38.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +41.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +44.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 6:        +50.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 7:        +40.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

nvme-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +42.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +81.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +42.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +44.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  

nct6798-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:                      904.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                        1.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in2:                        3.36 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in3:                        3.28 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in4:                        1.73 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                      312.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                      936.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in7:                        3.34 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in8:                        3.18 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in9:                        1.06 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:                       1.07 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                     960.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                       1.06 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                     608.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                     528.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                      617 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                     2005 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                      894 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                      732 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan6:                        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan7:                        0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                    +38.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:                    +40.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:                   +29.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:                   +22.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:                   +28.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                   +55.0°C    sensor = thermistor
PECI Agent 0 Calibration:  +40.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:      +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:              +0.0°C  
PCH_CPU_TEMP:               +0.0°C  
intrusion0:               ALARM
intrusion1:               ALARM
beep_enable:              disabled

enp5s0-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
PHY Temperature:  +44.6°C  
MAC Temperature:  +45.8°C  

nvme-pci-0700
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +43.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +81.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +43.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +45.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```